# pdo mysql driver in RHEL 7 is not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, mariadb, rhel

I'm trying to run my Laravel 5.7 app but will always get the error `Could not find driver` when trying to run a query in my page.

Here's portion of my .env code:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
```

Anyway instead of using mysql, we use MariaDB instead. I can confirm that mariadb is running without any problem because if I run `mysql -u root -p` in my terminal, I can connect to my MariaDB. Here's what my welcome message will be upon successfully log into my MariaDB.

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 44
Server version: 10.2.8-MariaDB MariaDB Server
```

Running `phpinfo()` will return this:

```
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers pgsql, sqlite

MySQL driver for PDO    George Schlossnagle, Wez Furlong, Ilia Alshanetsky, Johannes Schlueter
MySQLi  Zak Greant, Georg Richter, Andrey Hristov, Ulf Wendel
MySQLnd Andrey Hristov, Ulf Wendel, Georg Richter, Johannes Schlüter
```

But I can confirm my `/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules` folder contains `pdo_mysql.so`, `pdo.so`,`mysqli.so` and `mysqlnd.so`

And also my `/etc/opt/rh/rh-php71/php.d` folder contains `30-pdo_mysql.ini` on which it contains just one line, `extension=pdo_mysql.so`

So why isn't my pdo mysql running?

Comment: The `phpinfo()` line `PDO drivers pgsql, sqlite` line doesn't actually list mysql as a driver. Maybe you have to restart apache or nginx (or whatever you're using)?

Comment: You might check that selinux isn't blocking the driver or ini files.

Comment: @ourmandave yes I was puzzled why doesn't PDO drivers list mysql. I have restart apache several times. How do I check selinux isn't blocking the driver or ini files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I need to restart my php-fpm. Upon googling and googling, I still can't find the exact name of my php-fpm service, so I did `sudo find | grep fpm` and found out that my php-fpm service name is `rh-php71-php-fpm`

So I run `sudo service rh-php71-php-fpm restart` and `sudo systemctl restart httpd` and now mysql is listed under PDO drivers, and I can run my apps successfully.

Seriously, why did different versions of Linux have different names of the same thing?

Answer (score -2):

You can install php mysql connection package from yum

At first install #yum install epel-release -y then

## yum install php-mysqlnd -y